# How to change the name of column in query 2007 ACCESS DB

Tags: ms-access-2007, naming-conventions

Right now I have in my 2007 Access DB query:

Expr1: Switch([Medicaid]=-1,"Yes",[Medicaid]=0,"No")

yet the column name is showing "Expr1" on result....how do I change that to "Medicaid"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the name of a query column to the name of a table column, but you can change it to something similar:

```
 Medic aid: Switch([Medicaid]=-1,"Yes",[Medicaid]=0,"No")
```

You would probably be better off using Format:

```
 Medic aid: Format[Medicaid],"Yes/No")
```

Comment: Hi Holly, please see my addition.